# How to add cast extension to my Android app

Tags: android, casting, chromecast

I am developing my `Android app` for `PlayStore`. I wish enable the cast button feature on my app like `Youtube` does, so that it can be casted on to an `Android TV`.

**Is it possible to add `cast` extension to my app so that it can be casted to an Android TV?**
If yes, is a sample code I can look into ?

Googling about it, I get the following link asking to download the cast button. 
https://support.google.com/chromecast/answer/3212008?hl=en

But can't figure how to add the cast extension to my own app. *Is it possible at all ?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is extensive [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cast/) and a number of sample apps for Android, iOS and Chrome to accomplish that and more.